# Can't return a variable in a closure swift

Tags: swift, location, closures

i am trying to return the userlocation variable in my closure but i can't .
errror : unexpected a non void return value in void function
I know i can't return an int because it's already returning -> Void but i can't change it to int because it's saving geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground and everything .

```
@IBAction func add(sender: UIButton) {

PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
                (userlocation: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let point = userlocation where error == nil {
                    println(point.latitude)
                    println(point.longitude)

                    //let point = userlocation
                    var userlocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude: point.latitude, longitude: point.longitude)
                }
                return userlocation

            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The closure is not executed immediately, but at a later time – so it does not make sense to return something. You should use the user location (to update the view or something) while inside the closure.

Comment: The thing that am trying to upload the user location to parse so i have to retrieve the userlocation variable outside the closure ! after that code it should be something like that :   let post = Post()
        post.userlocation = userlocation!

Comment: Call the upload function inside the closure, or schedule it with GCD, passing user location as a parameter